# Caching for heavy writes and heavy reads on a PHP website

Tags: php, caching, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, couchbase

Currently we are facing an issue with IIS/PHP - we sometimes get "Service unavailable" errors for a website with heavy load. The server is running FastCGI, but don't use any opcode cache such as APC.

There is a 2.5KB XML file being written around minimum 20 times to disk every second - this is getting pricing updates from the commodity market. This is being used by a page for AJAX load every second or less. When the number of users go up we face an issue of php-cgi.exe processes queueing up and making the website unavailable.

Basically it is only one set of data being written and read.

We are planning to replace the file from disk using a CouchBase solution so that the file content would be written to the cache and read from the cache by the files.

My worry is this: "a cache is said to be good for less writes and more reads". How would CouchBase perform in this scenario of heavy writes and reads? Or does anyone have any other solutions for the above scenario?

We have tried storing and using this from MySQL database and then moved to a file based solution because MySQL was unable to handle the load.

Comment: Your description seems to be that there are 20 writes for every read.  How is that *heavy reads and writes*?  Wouldn't it be *heavy writes* with some reads?

Comment: There are about 15 similar sites running doing a similar operation. That is why it is heavy writes and reads.. and also it is minimum of 20 writes..

Comment: Not nearly enough info to go on here, I'm afraid, but: have you set up an opcode cache, such as APC? Does your PHP stack load into memory for each request (CGI) or does it persist in memory for speed (FastCGI etc)? What is the nature of the 2.5KB file? Can it be stored to memory, or a database record?

Comment: Mr. halfer, added some answers to your question as added info in the question itself.

Comment: You moved away from MySQL because it couldn't handle the load? I find this very unlikely. I would suggest code optimisation would of been more prudent.

Comment: (You need to use @halfer to notify someone directly, btw)

Comment: OK, the question is a bit better, though I still don't know what the XML is for. What is it _doing_? Why is it being written so often? Why are pages making an AJAX request every second - could you use Comet instead, if you are checking for something? If MySQL couldn't cope with something, maybe upgrade your server resources. What spec of machine are you using? Shared host, VPS, dedicated, etc?

Comment: @halfer, Thanks for the comment. This system produces the pricing details from a commodity market very often and this is being stored as a file in the disk. These prices are being pulled every second or so from the client.
I take your point about COMET. COMET generally pushes all the updates to all the subscribed clients and we don't need it. We can afford to miss a few inside a second. Also technically what we do is to send a request to the server to get the data from a file in disk and in case of comet this would have been stored in memory.

Comment: @halfer,That is why we are looking just to replace the disk file with the cache and seeking to know if writing the file to cache 20 times every second and reading from 5000+ clients would be safe with couchbase.

Comment: Personally I'd persist with MySQL. An update to a record 20 times/sec is a very low load indeed, so perhaps expand on why you gave up with this? (Aside: updates are generally better in the original question, rather than as many addendums, so new readers don't have to wade through many comments to see where we're at).

Comment: That said, install the PHP opcode cache first - that will be a big performance win, in my view.

Comment: There are some historical reasons which may go beyond the scope of this discussion and I don't want to waste your time :), but I'll try both your suggestions..

Comment: Do the maths - 2.5 * 20 = 50K per second. Peanuts. Your performance problem is somewhere else. BTW MySql writes/reads data to/from a hard disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used couchbase, and its way faster than mongodb or mysql.

have a look at this benchmark results: http://www.slideshare.net/renatko/couchbase-performance-benchmarking

For heavy writes, reads couchbase is a monster

Answer (score 1):

In Traditional SQL based databases, we're taught to try **not** to hit the database as much as possible.

In Couchbase, Reads and Writes are so fast they're trivial. Meaning you can perform a **far** increased amount, without increasing load compared to traditional RDBMS solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use database... For example, MySQL innodb, because insert will not lock the whole table.

Comment: Couchbase does not lock anything when you write into it

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase has been build from that, it is a very fast and scalable database.

Couchbase read/write directly in memory using memcache protocol (speed) and save the data to the disk (with replication to another node) asynchronously. This is how Couchbase is fast with read AND write.

Give it a try you will be surprised !